# Why a can't deploy my Astro + React project on Netlify when i use NetlifyCMS?

Tags: reactjs, netlify, astrojs, netlify-cms

I try to deploy my website (Astro + React + Netlify CMS + Tailwind)
https://github.com/bernaul/baptiste-clisson

Since i add React on this commit, my deployment fail :
https://github.com/bernaul/baptiste-clisson/commit/58754f55618e5c206b2a604614df35c9396520c5

I don't understand the error :

> 12:52:58 AM: building client
> 12:52:58 AM: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "netlify-cms-app" from "virtual:astro-netlify-cms/user-config".
> 12:52:58 AM: This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
> 12:52:58 AM: If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
> 12:52:58 AM: `build.rollupOptions.external`

[image]

I use React 18 and astro-netlify-cms ...

Have you any advice ? Should I externalize "netlify-cms-app" ? How ?

Thank you for your help,
Have a nice day

I try to remove react but my application is broken...

Answer (score 2):

one quick fix: downgrading to React 17 and installing netlify-cms-app as a direct dependency does seem to fix this:

```
npm i {,@types/}{react,react-dom}@^17 netlify-cms-app
```